# How to archive files and sub folders in a location to another place in linux

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to create a shell script to copy folders and files within those folders from one Linux machine to another linux machine. After copying I would like to delete only the files that are copied. I want to retain the folder structure as is.

Eg.

Machine X has a main folder named F with subfolders A,B,C folders in which each of them has 10 files.

I would like to make a copy in such a way that machine Y will have a folder named F with subfolders A,B,C containing the same files. Once the copy of all folders and files are complete, it should delete all the files in source folder but retain the folders.

Comment: It seems you forgot to include an actual question in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The code below is untested. Use with care and backup first.**

Something like this should get you started:

```
#!/bin/bash

srcdir=...

set -ex

rsync \
  --verbose \
  --recursive \
  "${srcdir}/" \
  user@host:/dstdir/

find "${srcdir}" -type f -delete
```

Set the `srcdir` variable and the remote argument to rsync to taste.

The rsync options are just from memory, so they may need tweaking. Read [the documentation](http://rsync.samba.org/ftp/rsync/rsync.html), especially options regarding deletion, backup, permissions and links.

<sup>(I'd rather not answer <del>questions</del> *requests* that show *no* signs of effort, but my fingers were itching, so there you go.)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Biffen. Below is what we did and got lost completely.

 #!/bin/sh  
scp -r /root/Desktop/india /root/test  
cd /root/test/india/  
tar cvf /root/Desktop/`date +\%Y\%m\%d`.tar * --rm /  
rm -rf /root/test/*  
find /root/Desktop/india/ -name *.txt -delete  
find /root/Desktop/india/ -name *.edi -delete  
scp -p /root/Desktop/*.tar root@192.168.96.137:/root/Desktop  
rm -rf /root/Desktop/`date +\%Y\%m\%d`.tar  

We were trying to make a copy of the files then zip it move it to remote system but things didn't go as planned.

Comment: @VinodBalakrishnan I can  hardly read that. Are you saying things are working now?

Comment: @ Biffen : I meant to say your script did the job what i was looking for. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

scp the files, check the exit code of the scp and then delete the files locally.

Something like `scp files user@remotehost:/path/ && rm files`

If scp has failed, the second part of the command won't execute

Comment: This won't recreate the directory structure on the remote machine, though.

Comment: use scp -r if you want to copy directories